# Laravel Homestead - one per project or one for all?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Vagrant Homestead for my regular work with Laravel projects. **Let's assume that I'm talking just about Homestead (no other vagrant boxes.).** I have both `.vagrant.d` and `Homestead` directories in my `~` directory. Cool.

I know that I can deal with more than one Laravel project in Homestead by simply adding more `sites` and `folders` to my YAML file, editing my `/etc/hosts` and finally inside `Homestead` I can run `vagrant up` / `vagrant ssh` etc.

Question is more about how do prefer to organise your projects (if you have more than one). Is it better to:

**1)** add more `sites` and `folders` to one Homestead

or

**2)** is it better to create something like `Boxes` directory inside my `home` and then clone as many Homesteads as possible by naming them like

- Homestead_proj_1
- Homestead_proj_2 etc

So one virtual machine per project or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use one VM for all my projects unless there is a compelling reason to have multiple VMs, see my setup below.

I like my VM to match my server configuration. If the server configuration is different for production I will set up an new VM that matches.

Also, I tend to give individual clients their own VMs on any decent sized project.

In general it is a pain to manage multiple VMs, so why give yourself the headache unless it is warranted.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects  
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: app1.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/app1/public

    - map: app2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/app2/public

    - map: app2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/app3/public 

databases:
    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
```